# How to fetch events from eventhub from a timer enabled azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am working with Azure Event Hubs. My requirement is to fetch the events from Azure Event Hub, using azure function on a daily basis. Basically my azure function will be timer enabled. It should be able to fetch the data from azure event hubs. Is there a mechanism for this ?
I am aware that we can trigger a azure function whenever an event is received at event hub. This i don't want as the function will execute n number of time. I want to just fetch the events on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can still create a timer triggered function and create consumer clients in your code to receive events. See sample code below. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Consumer;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp7
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        const string EventHubsConnectionString = "your connection string";
        const string EventHubName = "evethub name";
        const string ConsumerGroupName = "cgname";

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            // You better dissover partitions by eventhub client. I am just hardcoding them here for now.
            var partitions = new List<string> { "0", "1" };
            var receiveTasks = new List<Task>();

            foreach(var p in partitions)
            {
                receiveTasks.Add(ReadEventsFromPartition(p));
            }

            // Wait until all reads complete.
            Task.WhenAll(receiveTasks);
        }

        public static async Task ReadEventsFromPartition(string partitionId)
        {
            await using (var consumer = new EventHubConsumerClient(ConsumerGroupName, EventHubsConnectionString, EventHubName))
            {
                EventPosition startingPosition = EventPosition.FromOffset(CheckpointStore.ReadOffsetForPartition(partitionId));

                long lastOffset = -1;

                await foreach (PartitionEvent receivedEvent in consumer.ReadEventsFromPartitionAsync(partitionId, startingPosition))
                {
                    // Process received events here.

                    // Break if no events left.
                    if (receivedEvent.Data == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    lastOffset = receivedEvent.Data.Offset;
                }

                // Persist last event's offset so we can continue reading from this position next time function is triggered.
                if (lastOffset != -1)
                {
                    // Write offset into some durable store.
                    CheckpointStore.WriteOffsetForPartition(partitionId, lastOffset);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can find code snippets for JS here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/get-started-node-send-v2

Comment: Yes, but this read data from a blobstorage using it as checkpoint store. I need to directly ready from eventhub periodically, using a timer triggered azure function. Is that possible?